# How to mount a virtual floppy disk into a virtual machine?

Tags: kvm, qemu

I'm using qemu-system-x86_64 to start a virtual machine, but I absolutely can't figure out how to mount a virtual floppy disk (vfd file) into it.

If I want to mount an iso, that is easy:

```
-drive "file=/path/to/iso/file.iso,index=1,media=cdrom"
```

If I want to mount a drive, that is easy as well:

```
-drive id=disk0,if=virtio,cache.direct=on,if=virtio,aio=native,format=raw,file=/path/to/drive/image
```

I even managed to find out how I could mount a physical drive:

```
-drive file=/path/to/drive,if=virtio
```

But I couldn't find a single example on how to mount a vfd.

Answer (score 8):

**The short way:**

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -fda /path/to/floppy.img
```

I've heard of QEMU command-line options similar to this one described as "convenience flags".

**The long way:**

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=/path/to/floppy.img,index=0,if=floppy,format=raw
```

This option is [apparently deprecated](https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/vai_qemu_jungle/attachments/slides/2539/export/events/attachments/vai_qemu_jungle/slides/2539/qemu_cli_jungle.pdf).

**The "modern" way:**

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -blockdev driver=file,node-name=f0,filename=/path/to/floppy.img -device floppy,drive=f0
```

Note that devices attached this way tend not to cooperate well with older QEMU functionality such as the `-snapshot` flag and the monitor command `change`.

**On-the-fly:**

> (qemu) change floppy0 /path/to/floppy.img

This is a [monitor](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor#change) command for managing removable media after the emulator has already started. `info block` will print the name of the floppy device if its name isn't "floppy0".

---

Other (?) ways:

Peruse the [online manual](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html) and in-tree [docs](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/tree/master/docs) for more ideas. [QMP](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/QMP) could probably attach floppy images dynamically, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Wow thanks, On-the-fly unfortunately is not an option for me. And since I'd rather avoid deprecated options and I'd like to use the snapshot flag, I'll have to go with `The short way`, right?